# Core Data Predicate "Unable to parse the format string"

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, format-string

I'm trying to fetch a set of `NSManagedObjects` that have specific relationships to other objects.

So I have 4 managed objects: `UserPick`, `Game`, `Group`, `User`.  The UserPick has to-one relationship to `Game`, `Group`, `User` individually.  I need to find all `UserPick`s that have a specific `Game`, `Group` and `User`, but I cannot seem to structure the predicate correctly:

I've tried:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K = %@, %K = %@, %K = %@",
UserPickRelationships.game, game,
UserPickRelationships.group, group,
UserPickRelationships.user, user]
```

and:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K = %@, %K = %@, %K = %@",
UserPickRelationships.game, game.objectID,
UserPickRelationships.group, group.objectID,
UserPickRelationships.user, user.objectID]
```

finally:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K.%K = %@, %K.%K = %@, %K.%K = %@",
UserPickRelationships.game, @"objectID", game.objectID,
UserPickRelationships.group, @"objectID", group.objectID,
UserPickRelationships.user, @"objectID", user.objectID]
```

I've tried using `%@` and `%K` in every conceivable combination.  All I ever get back is: `NSPredicate cannot parse format string`.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to combine the conditions with "AND":

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K = %@ AND %K = %@ AND %K = %@",
UserPickRelationships.game, game,
UserPickRelationships.group, group,
UserPickRelationships.user, user]
```

(assuming that `UserPickRelationships.game` evaluates to the string `"game"`).

Comment: good god, that was a dumb mistake.  Thank you.  I think I will go grab another cup of coffee now...